# Reorder list after dynamically populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

i have this list that i am populating programmatically.

```
<ul id="topNavigation" class="topNavigation" runat="server"></ul>
```

here is the code for the list items

```
foreach (var node in children)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            span.Attributes.Add("class", "editableLinks");
            span.Attributes.Add("data-id", node.id.ToString());


            var child = new Node(node.id);
            if (child.Name.Contains("contact"))
                break;

            var sortOrder = child.GetProperty("sortOrder");
            if (sortOrder != null)
                span.Attributes.Add("data-sort", sortOrder.Value);
            var hidden = "";
            var deleted = "0";
            var naviHide = child.GetProperty("umbracoNaviHide");
            var userDeleted = child.GetProperty("userDeleted");
            if (naviHide != null)
            {
                hidden = naviHide.Value;
                if (userDeleted != null)
                    deleted = userDeleted.Value;
               // nav.InnerText += naviHide.Value;

                if (hidden != "1" && deleted !="1")
                {
                    topNavigation.Controls.Add(li);
                    var anchor = new HyperLink();
                    var title= child.GetProperty("title");
                    //anchor.Text=child.Id.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title.Value))
                       span.InnerHtml = title.Value;
                    else
                    {
                        var name = child.Name.Split('_');
                        span.InnerHtml = name[1];
                    }

                    if (child.Id == Node.GetCurrent().Id)
                        li.Attributes.Add("class", "current");

                        anchor.CssClass = "navigation";
                    if (!host.Contains("testcms"))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(child.GetProperty("umbracoUrlAlias").Value))
                            anchor.NavigateUrl = "/"+child.GetProperty("umbracoUrlAlias").Value;
                        else
                            anchor.NavigateUrl = child.NiceUrl;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var id = "/" + child.Id.ToString();

                        anchor.NavigateUrl = id;
                        //anchor.NavigateUrl=anchor.NavigateUrl.Replace("usercontrols", "");
                    }
                    anchor.Controls.Add(span);
                       li.Controls.Add(anchor);
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to order the list items by the sortOrder value pulled in this function? At the moment i am reordering it through javascript but on some places where this is used javascript cannot be used.

Comment: Does each child have the same sort order? Or another way, what happens if the sort order is different for different children.

Comment: no they do not. but to get the sort order i have to go into the childnode through the getproperty function. I am setting the value of each sort order in the span in each anchor tag inside the list item.

Comment: If you have different sort orders, then I'm unclear about how you want the list sorted.  Can you give an example of the data, possible sort orders, and how you would like the list to end up? Or is the sort-order a value which indicates which position the item is at?

Comment: The issue im having is how to reorder the list on the frontend by the property in the child node. after it goes through and adds them to the list the sort order value is in the span of each list item. I am just not sure how to make it reorder the list after its creation.

Comment: the sort order is the position i want the item to be at but as of now there is no way of sorting the list by those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have some type of outer element to which you are adding your `li` instances.  In that case, you just need to build your object into a different list and then sort it before adding to the outer object. You will need to pull in the LINQ namespace for the `Select` and `OrderBy` methods.

```
using System.Linq;

// Holder for the data coming out of your internal for each converted
// to a transformation function
class ListNode
{
   // or whatever comparable type your sort order is
   int SortOrder {get;set;}
   HttpGenericControl Li {get; set;}
}

// Convert function is your code inside the foreach returning the
// HttpGenericControl li from each loop same code except for the return
ListNode ConvertChildToLi(ChildClass child) 
{
    // Same code here to the end of the for loop
    return new ListNode { SortOrder = sortOrder, Li = li };
}
```

then in your calling function

```
var liControls = children.Select(ConvertChildToLi).OrderBy(n=> n.SortOrder);
foreach(var li in liControls) 
{
   // Assuming outer element ul exists
   ul.Controls.Add(li);
}
```